# Form Validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I have made a cart-mechanism using PHP and done validation with the help of JavaScript and the validation is not working.

This is my actual php script:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  $fieldidval[] = $row['product_id'];
  $fieldnameval[] = $row['product_name'];
  $fieldcostval[] = $row['product_cost'];
  $fieldimgval[] = $row['product_image'];
  $fielddescval[] = $row['product_description'];

}

//printing field values

for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++){

  echo "<tr><form action = 'cart.php?pid=" . $fieldidval[$i] . "&name=" .$fieldnameval[$i] . "&cost=" . $fieldcostval[$i] . "' method = 'post' name = 'tocart' onsubmit = 'return(validateAll());'><td>" . $fieldnameval[$i] . "</td><td>" . $fieldcostval[$i] . "</td><td>" . $fieldimgval[$i] . "</td><td>" . $fielddescval[$i] . "</td><td><input type = 'text' name ='qty_input[$i]' ></td><td><input type = 'submit' name = 'submit'></td></form></tr>"; }
```

and this is my validation in javascript:

```
function validateAll(){
  if( document.tocart.qty_input[0].value == "" ){
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
    document.tocart.qty_input.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

When I hit submit nothing works.

Comment: Please click the `<>` add RENDERED HTML and COMPLETE JS  - we do not care about the PHP since the issue is JS Client side. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Also: `onsubmit = 'return validateAll(this);'` using `function validateAll(form) { var qty_input= form["qty_input[0]"];
  if( qty_input.value == "" ) {  alert("Please enter a valid number");
    qty_input.focus();
    return false; }}`

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you the given code works.

Comment: @mplungjan and why are we using `this`?  I took a working example from the net. Could you please elaborate to better my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer

If we keep the inline submit handler, pass the form using `this`

```
onsubmit = 'return validateAll(this);'
```

Then we can access the form directly in the handler without having to use the longer document.formname

```
function validateAll(form) { // "this" -> whatever is in (....) here
  var qty_input= form["qty_input[0]"]; 
  if (qty_input.value == "") { 
    alert("Please enter a valid number"); 
     qty_input.focus(); 
     return false; 
  }
}
```

Here is a better way using unobtrusive code

```
window.onload=function() { // when page loads. You can use event listener too
  document.querySelector("[name=tocart]").onsubmit=function() {
    var qty_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[name^=qty_input]"); // starts with
    for (var i=0;i<qty_inputs.length;i++) { 
      if (qty_inputs[i].value == "") { 
         alert("Please enter a valid number"); 
         qty_inputs[i].focus(); 
         return false; 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And all this can be avoided by using

```
<input type = 'text' name ='qty_input[$i]' required />
```

Comment: So what you mean to say that there is no need for javascript form validation scripts and I could just use `required` at the end of each input tag? Wouldn't that have any consequences?

Comment: That is correct if you only want to test for blank. Also repeat the test on the server to be sure

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks, your answer helped me alot.

Comment: You are welcome. You can change the accept to my answer seeing I was first to give the solution